# DefaultSaveFormat for Powerpoint 2010

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2010

How do I set the DefaultSaveFormat for Powerpoint 2010 for the Powerpoint with macro version?

Comment: It's not clear to me whether you're asking how to change the Default Save Format of Powerpoint 2010 to one that includes macros (.pptm) or whether you want to use a macro to change the Default Save Format. Which one is it?

Answer (score 0):

In code, there's a constant that tells PPT to save as Default ... meaning in whatever format PPT deems correct.  You can't force that, but you can, again in code, tell PPT to save in any specific format.

You can change the format it saves in by default when the USER does a File | Save As in the File | Options | Save dialog box.